# prove that $\sum_{i+j+k=p}{p\choose i+j+k}x^iy^jz^k\equiv x^p+y^p+z^p\pmod{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let $x,y,z$ be integers and $p$ an odd integer.How can I prove that $$\sum_{i+j+k=p}{p\choose i+j+k}x^iy^jz^k\equiv x^p+y^p+z^p\pmod{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}$$

Comment: Hint: The sum is $(x+y+z)^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to prove that the polynomial $f=(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$ divides the  polynomial $g=(x+y+z)^p-(x^p+y^p+z^p).$ It is enouth to show that all roots of $f$ are roots and for $g.$ Take, for example,  a root  $x=-y$ and put into $g$. We get $z^p-( (-y)^p+y^p+z^p)=0$ for odd $p$. Thus $g=(x+y)g_1$ for some polynomial $g_1.$ In a similar way working with $x=-z$ and $y=-z$ we get that $g=0 \mod (x+y)(x+z)(y+z).$

Comment: Thanks for input. Would you happen to figure out what the summation expression of that polynomial of degree n-3 is?

Comment: what is $n?$...

Comment: Let say an odd prime

Comment: I can choose any n and wolfram will do the rest. But I wanna know what the general expression is like.

Comment: I mean  - in your question there is no any $n.$ So, what is $n?$

Comment: Sorry, I meant p.

Comment: No matter. Just $p-3$ must be odd.

Comment: Nope. $p-3$ is even since p is odd.

Comment: Well, in your question $p$ is odd and  that formula is wrong for $p-3.$

Comment: suppose that p=5, f(x,y,z)= 5(x^2+y^2+z^2+ xy+ yz+zx). What is the summation notation of that expression?

Comment: $$(x+y+z)^p-(x^p+y^p+z^p)=f(x,y,z)(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$$ I would like to know the summation notation of $f(x,y,z)$. I hope this is much clearer. Let me give you your due credit and ask another question. Thanks.